# Grub fatal error while installing ubuntu, please help

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I'm having a lot of trouble right now, with Ubuntu. I tried installing it from a usb, and it installed everything except Grub, in which it ran into a fatal error. I tried manually installing Grub using the terminal, from what I could find online, but nothing worked. I was installing it alongside the Windows I already had on the system, but now I cannot enter Windows because I get put into Grub Rescue, whatever that is. Can somebody please help me fix the Grub installation issue, because I have some data in Windows that I don't want lost? Thanks in advance.

PS. Please do not assume any knowledge on my part, I am very new to Linux so please explain in detail.

Comment: Not assuming any special knowledge but one question needs to be answered (and edited in), BIOS or UEFI? Any preinstalled Windows 8 or newer is in UEFI mode so, that being the case, please check UEFI settings > Boot before anything else.

Comment: If UEFI, you should be able to go to UEFI boot menu, often f12, but varies by brand & directly boot Windows. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair